# Keys in object include characters that aren't allowed in identifiers

Tags: javascript

In my code I have this variable:

```
const operatorPrice = this.state.operatorPrice;
```

The value of operatorPrice is an object that looks like such:

[image]

Now, I want to put those into two separate Tables like such:

**4/28/2022**

```
    name       price   category
    product1    $20      oil
```

**5/28/2022**

```
    name       price   category
   product1    $20      oil
```

However I am getting this error: [image: error]

I guess I understand that the value of this.state.operatorPrice is not an array but I don't know in this format how to access the data and break it up. Any help or documentation would be awesome.

Comment: `4/28/2022: [id: name: category: isTaxable: ]` this is **not** how JavaScript objects look like...

Comment: @TobiasS. Console.log is listed above, looks pretty close to me,  maybe you can also help me understand the difference?

Comment: It appears to be an object, with keys consisting of those dates. Like with any object, you can use `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` to get the keys (and values) on that object.

Comment: @JeffMercado I am using object.entries but getting no data back, i am assuming that I am working off the top layer only so how do I go a layer deeper to get to the individual properties in like a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in this object here include characters that aren't valid in normal identifiers. You can't for example access it like this:

```
operatorPrice.4/28/2022
```

That's clearly not valid! JavaScript would interpret that key as division with numbers.

Instead you have to use bracket notation to access it:

```
operatorPrice["4/28/2022"]
```

Note that unlike using dot notation, any expression can be used within the brackets, so this also does the same as above:

```
operatorPrice[["4", "28", "2022"].join("/")]
// or even just
operatorPrice[[4, 28, 2022].join("/")]
```

---

As @JeffMercado suggests, you should use `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` to get the keys (and corresponding entries if required).

```
const keys = Object.keys(operatorPrice);

keys.forEach((key) => {
    operatorPrice[key]; // bracket notation again!
});
```

Comment: This is great stuff! I still dont know if I understand how to access the array data from key value pair. I've never done it and so I dont fully understand how to get to the data with the key. Again this is very helpful so any documentation that can point me in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: @MambaForever https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors